# Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit webkitwidgets creating a click package on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, webkit

hope you're well. Does anyone know how to solve this error 
:-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit webkitwidgets creating a click package:-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit webkitwidgets 
when creating a click package?  Already installed:

> sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev

It was working well so far debugging locally but getting the error back when trying to publish my programme.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use webengine and webenginewidgets instead.

webkit and other related classes has been replaced by webengine .
Go through the following guide to learm how to port webkit project to webengine project.

http://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine/Porting_from_QtWebKit

Comment: Thanks, and although this is correct I cannot get the webengine libraries to be detected.  I ended reinstalling Qt Creator and ensuring the modules were installed and even though it wouldn't work.